# Why Bootstrap selectpicker javascript function is not working in asp?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

Bootstrap selectpicker javascript function is not working in asp.

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
       });
 </script>
```

Asp code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" CssClass="selectpicker" data-style="btn-danger" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Action</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Another action</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Something else here</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the HTML output?  Do you get a JS error or does nothing happen?

Comment: asp:DropDownList list is a server side controls and probably it does not support javascript functions , you should client side controls for this! eg: <select>

Comment: @Jake745 - he's selecting it based on css class, so that shouldn't be the problem. OP - do you have any javascript errors on your page?

Comment: No javascript errors on the page!

Comment: Can you paste the html output of your page (if it small enough)?  Have you referenced the appropriate script libraries (bootstrap selectpicker and jquery)?

Comment: Yes! i've referenced appropriate script libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`